# Help with a header for a cls and tex

Tags: header-footer, author, mwcls

Im using this code in the CLS to make the header in the TEX
the problem im having is to define the author and their data separated all I can find is the authors in a single line and then the \afill, and I'm trying to:

first i wanted to be able to make size \center but the beginning and end of the title smaller.

then i need the authors aligned \flushleft like the example down and aligned with the title also:

Joh Smi
Faculdade de ORCID 0000-0000-0000-0000
Ant Sil
Faculdade de ORCID 0000-0000-0000-0000
Lorenzo Ortiz
Faculdade de ORCID 0000-0000-0000-0000

im using this code is cls to make the authors

```
\LoadClass{article}
\renewcommand\normalsize{
    \@setfontsize\normalsize{12}{12}}
\RequirePackage{natbib}%bibliografia
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[a4paper, margin=25mm, headsep=15mm, footskip=15mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\RequirePackage{titling}
\pretitle{
    \begin{center}
    \fontsize{14}{14} \selectfont \bfseries}
\posttitle{
    \par
    \end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
\preauthor{
    \begin{noindent}
        \fontsize{10}{10} \selectfont 
    \renewcommand\Affilfont{\fontsize{10}{10} \selectfont}}
\postauthor{
    \end{noindent}
    \par}




\RequirePackage{authblk}

\renewcommand\Authsep{,}

\renewcommand\Authand{,}

\renewcommand\Authands{,}
```

in TEX file I'm using

````
\affil[]{local name and town}```

Thanks for the help and sorry if I'm not explaining myself well.
I'm real new in latex and not from an English natural language country.
````

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting fragments of a document class, and fragments of your document, edit your question to   us what class you are actually using, and provide a link to it if it's not part of the standard distribution. Additionally, create a minimal document using the class that people can play with. It shouldn't need much more than  `\documentclass{...} \begin{document}\maketitle\end{documentclass}` with your example titling code included. Since the class is using the `authblk` package, then that's the place to start: https://texdoc.org/pkg/authblk

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some weeks of looking for it finally I found the right answer:

In https://ctan.org/pkg/titling look for the package authblk

At the end you will find that using the command blocks will do the trick.

In my case was:

\RequirePackage[blocks]{authblk}

Thanks for the help.

Rui Silva